# Table with check boxes in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to put a list of objects on a wiki page for several teams to mark the objects they use. To do this, I made a table with a column for each team and would like to put a check box in those columns for the teams to mark.

This is the basic idea of what I'm looking to do:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Object Usage by Team</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Object</th>
            <th>Team 1</th>
            <th>Team 2</th>
            <th>Team 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Object 1</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="Team" value="Team 1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="Team" value="Team 2"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="Team" value="Team 3"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to do a table with check box cells in MediaWiki and store the check box state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use one of those extensions for inserting a form in your article:

- [Semantic Forms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms)
- [Simple Forms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Simple_Forms)
- [HTMLets](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HTMLets)

The easiest way, if you are happy with users checking the boxes using wikicode (editing the page), is by using [Extension:Chklist](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Chklist)

Syntax is as simple as this

```
<chklist>
[x] Checked item
[] Unchecked item
</chklist>
```

If none of those extensions help you, maybe creating an extension of your own is the way to go.

**Update 08/2018**
[Extension:Chklist](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Chklist) has been archived by mediawiki and there is a warning about a major security risk as it vulnerable to Cross-site scripting attacks.

[Extension:Checklist](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Checklist) could be used as a replacement, last update was in 2018/04/18 as this edit is made. 
Though, i didn't use it, and don't know its syntax.